# Check property of an exception with NUnit 2.6

Tags: c#, nunit

What is the most idiomatic way with NUnit 2.6 to check equality of a property of an exception?

Code I'd like to write but *does **not*** work: `Expected 3, but was <empty>`

```
Assert.That(() => someObject.MethodThrows(),
  Throws.TypeOf<SomeException>().With.Property("Data").Count.EqualTo(3), /* Data is a collection */
  "Exception expected");
```

I could use nested `Assert` expressions, but that seems overly complicated and unnecessary:

```
  Assert.AreEqual(3,
    Assert.Throws<SomeException>(
      () => someObject.MethodThrows(),
      "Exception expected").Data.Count);
```

**edit** In fact, the first code example does work. I don't know why it did not work several times before posting this question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't speak to NUnit 2.6, but on NUnit 2.5 the following test:

```vb
Public Class MyException
    Inherits Exception
    Public Property SomeList As New List(Of String) From {"hello", "world"}
End Class

<TestFixture()>
Public Class TestClass1
    Public Shared Sub DoSomething()
        Throw New MyException()
    End Sub

    <Test()>
    Public Sub TestExample()
        Assert.That(Sub() DoSomething(), Throws.TypeOf(Of MyException)().With.Property("SomeList").Count.EqualTo(3))
    End Sub
End Class
```

produces this following error message:

```
Expected: <ClassLibrary1.MyException> and property SomeList property Count equal to 3
But was:  < "hello", "world" >
```

Could this just be a regression in the NUnit 2.6 beta?

Comment: hm. there has had to be something else wrong with my code. it works now :-/ as a side remark: uuuagh, vb.net!!

Comment: Glad to hear it worked, as far as VB.NET goes.. well, it pays bills and more :P

Answer (score 1):

I would go with this:

```
var exception = Assert.Throws<SomeException>(() => someObject.MethodThrows(),
                                             "Exception expected")
Assert.AreEqual(3, exception.Data.Count);
```

This is the clearest you can get:

- Unlike your first example, this is refactoring safe
- It asserts one thing at a time, not multiple like both of your examples.

Comment: But this is still the same as my code, except for making `exception` a local variable?

Comment: Yes, sure. You are asserting two things, so you should have two asserts.

Comment: Daniel, what about patterns along the lines of `Assert.That(() => o.Throws(), Throws.TypeOf<SomeException>().With.Message.Contains("xxx"));`? To me both look quite similar

Comment: @knittl: Yes, they are. I don't like this example either. As I said: One assert per row, not multiple. BTW: Why do you use `With.Property("Data")` instead of just `With.Data` in your first example?

Comment: @knittl: BTW: I think your first example works correctly. Data doesn't contain anything and that's what the message tells you!

Comment: It works now mysteriously … thanks for your good answer though